# Spark: Is "count" on Grouped Data a Transformation or an Action?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know that [`count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/programming-guide.html#actions) called on an RDD or a DataFrame is an action. But while fiddling with the spark shell, I observed the following

```
scala> val empDF = Seq((1,"James Gordon", 30, "Homicide"),(2,"Harvey Bullock", 35, "Homicide"),(3,"Kristen Kringle", 28, "Records"),(4,"Edward Nygma", 30, "Forensics"),(5,"Leslie Thompkins", 31, "Forensics")).toDF("id", "name", "age", "department")
empDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string, age: int, department: string]

scala> empDF.show
+---+----------------+---+----------+
| id|            name|age|department|
+---+----------------+---+----------+
|  1|    James Gordon| 30|  Homicide|
|  2|  Harvey Bullock| 35|  Homicide|
|  3| Kristen Kringle| 28|   Records|
|  4|    Edward Nygma| 30| Forensics|
|  5|Leslie Thompkins| 31| Forensics|
+---+----------------+---+----------+

scala> empDF.groupBy("department").count //count returned a DataFrame
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [department: string, count: bigint]

scala> res1.show
+----------+-----+                                                              
|department|count|
+----------+-----+
|  Homicide|    2|
|   Records|    1|
| Forensics|    2|
+----------+-----+
```

When I called `count` on GroupedData (`empDF.groupBy("department")`), I got another DataFrame as the result (res1). This leads me to believe that `count` in this case was a transformation. It is further supported by the fact that no computations were triggered when I called `count`, instead, they started when I ran `res1.show`.

I haven't been able to find any documentation that suggests `count` could be a transformation as well. Could someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.count()` what you have used in your code is over `RelationalGroupedDataset`, which creates a new column with count of elements in the grouped dataset. This is a **transformation**. Refer:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedDataset

The `.count()` that you use normally over `RDD/DataFrame/Dataset` is completely different from the above and this `.count()` is an **Action**. Refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

EDIT:

always use `.count()` with `.agg()` while operating on groupedDataSet in order to avoid confusion in future:

```
empDF.groupBy($"department").agg(count($"department") as "countDepartment").show
```

Answer (score 8):

**Case 1:**

You  use `rdd.count()` to count the number of rows. Since it initiates the DAG execution and returns the data to the driver, its an **action** for RDD.

for ex: `rdd.count // it returns a Long value`

**Case 2:**

If you call count on Dataframe, it initiates the DAG execution and returns the data to the driver, its an **action** for Dataframe.

for ex: `df.count // it returns a Long value`

**Case 3:**

In your case you are calling `groupBy` on `dataframe` which returns `RelationalGroupedDataset` object, and you are calling `count` on grouped Dataset which returns a `Dataframe`, so its a **transformation** since it doesn't gets the data to the driver and initiates the DAG execution.

for ex:

```
 df.groupBy("department") // returns RelationalGroupedDataset
          .count // returns a Dataframe so a transformation
          .count // returns a Long value since called on DF so an action
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've already figure out - if method returns a distributed object (`Dataset` or `RDD`) it can be qualified as a transformations.

However these distinctions are much better suited for RDDs than Datasets. The latter ones features an optimizer, including recently added cost based optimizer, and might be much less lazy the old API, blurring differences between transformation and action in some case.

Here however it is safe to say `count` is a transformation.