# Scala concatenate Column of Array[String] into single Array[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, data-science

I have a Spark Dataframe (Scala) with an `id - (Int)` and `tokens - (array<string>)` column:

```
id,tokens
0,["a","b","c"]
1,["a","b"]
...
```

Assuming I am able to retrieve the data via a SparkSession and casting to a case class:

```
case class Token(id: Int, tokens: Array[String])
```

After getting a `Dataset[Token]` object, how do I concatenate all the array of string tokens into a single `Array<String>` and subsequently perform a count to find the most occuring strings?

Output:

```
a,2
b,2
c,1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `explode` the token column & take the count after grouping by the individual tokens:

```
scala> val input = sc.parallelize(List(
  (0, Array("a","b","c")), 
  (1, Array("a","b"))
)).toDF("id","token")

scala> input.withColumn("token_split",explode($"token"))
         .groupBy($"token_split")
         .agg(count($"id") as "count")
         .orderBy($"count".desc)
         .show
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-----+
|token_split|count|
+-----------+-----+
|          b|    2|
|          a|    2|
|          c|    1|
+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! To add on, we can use `.count()` instead of `agg(count($"id") as "count")` :)

Comment: @Ivan, yes thats true, even `.count()` works. I have explicitly used `.agg()` inorder to avoid confusions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966347/spark-is-count-on-grouped-data-a-transformation-or-an-action